# How to calculate best rating based on the combination of rating number and number of ratings

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, rating

Im building a movie recommendation system. The recommendation has been calculated at this point. I have a dataframe in pandas (using python - machine learning problem) and this dataset has 3 columns: movie name, movie rating, and number of ratings. I can easily find the best rating by using highest value of course. I want to find the best rating based upon not only the rating value but also on the number of ratings provided. In instance: I have a movie toy story which is rated 8.8 by 222 people. I have another movie called coco rated 8.9 by 131 people. Based on this despite coco being rated higher I need a calculation that will inform me that toy story is the highest rated movie theoetically as it has somewhat close to twice the amount of ratings. Any help is always appreciated as I am a student and still learning.

```
import pandas as pd

#creating empty lists to form dataset
movie_names_list = []
movie_ratings_list =  []
movie_number_of_ratings_list = []

#entry 1
movie_names_list.append("Toy story")
movie_ratings_list.append(8.8)
movie_number_of_ratings_list.append(222)

#entry 2
movie_names_list.append("Coco")
movie_ratings_list.append(8.9)
movie_number_of_ratings_list.append(131)

#entry 3
movie_names_list.append("Frozen")
movie_ratings_list.append(8.5)
movie_number_of_ratings_list.append(275)

movie_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Movie_Name':movie_names_list,
    'Movie_Rating':movie_ratings_list,
    'Rated_By_Number_Of_Users':movie_number_of_ratings_list
    })

movie_df.head(5)
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar case where I needed to weight users ratings with number of rates and a score. I used this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/942965/116406 where is a weighted mean

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself after trying many methods...

- Step 1: is to find a weight value automatically that will be applied to both movies to measure and compute a given movie's weight percentage based on the number of ratings the movie has. In this scenario 2 movies: toy story and coco from the above example will be compared. The formula for the automatic calculation of weight value is: weight = total_number_of_reviews_in_dataframe (from all movies - both toy story and coco) / 100.

**Answer: weight = (222 + 131) / 100 = 3.53.**

- Step 2: for both movies, we will calculate the weight that the number of ratings will carry in the determination of finding the highest-rated movie. Importantly, the weight percentage from both movies, when combined, should equal 100. The formula for movie weight calculation is: movie_weight = number_of_ratings_for_movie / weight from step 1.

**Answer:**

**Toy Story: 222 / 3.53 = 62.88.**

**Coco: 131 / 3.53 = 37.11.**

- Step 3: calculate a weight-based total for both movies. The formula for this is: movie_weight_based_total = movie_weight (from step 2) * rating_for_movie (the average rating).

**Answer:**

**Toy Story: 62.88 * 8.8 = 553.344.**

**Coco: 37.11 * 8.9 = 330.279.**

- Final step: use a conditional statement to find what total is higher and the answer to this is the best-rated movie :)

Python code addition below (can easily make a function out of this):

```
#calculate the weight that will be used to compute and measure the best rated movie 
weight_for_rating_calculation = movie_df['Rated_By_Number_Of_Users'].sum() / 100

#for both movies calculate the wieght that the number of ratings will carry in the determination of finding the highest rated movie
movie_1_weight = movie_df.iloc[0]['Rated_By_Number_Of_Users'] / weight_for_rating_calculation # toy story
movie_2_weight = movie_df.iloc[1]['Rated_By_Number_Of_Users'] / weight_for_rating_calculation # coco

#calculate a weight-based total for both movies
movie_1_weight_based_total = movie_1_weight * movie_df.iloc[0]['Movie_Rating']
movie_2_weight_based_total = movie_2_weight * movie_df.iloc[1]['Movie_Rating']

#which ever total is higher is the best-rated movie now based upon the combination of both rating value and number of ratings
if (movie_1_weight_based_total > movie_2_weight_based_total):
  print("Toy Story is the best rated movie")
else:
  ("Coco is the best rated movie")
```